# How to add a space between first two columns? The format is extremely strict

Tags: awk

I have a file like this, the first three rows are correct, the following rows are wrong. I need to add a space between the first and the second column for the wrong rows. Nothing else can be changed. I tried to use awk. Please help me out. Thank you.
[image: rdseed.site]

Comment: As @fedorqui has already said below: please don't paste _images_ of sample data - it prevents copy & paste for testing possible solutions.

Comment: Sure, i won't do it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using reverse fields, if there are only spaces:

```
awk -F'[^ ]*' 'length($2)<4{sub($2,"    ")}1' file
```

or changing every line, taking the first line as reference:

```
awk -F'[^ ]*' 'NR==1{f=$2}{sub($2,f)}1' file
```

or just changing every line to 4 spaces between the first and second column:

```
awk -F'[^ ]*' '{sub($2,"    ")}1' file
```

----edit----

Explanation of the first one. With "columns" in this explanation I mean the columns, as if the default field separator were used:

```
awk -F'[^ ]*' '     # Use any set of non-space characters ([^ ]*) as field separator. 
                    # This means that the first field ($1) becomes an empty field
                    # (before the first column and the second field ($2) contains the
                    # spaces between the first column and the second column.
  length($2)<4 {    # If the length of that field is less then 4 (the nr. of spaces) 
    sub($2,"    ")  # Then substitute the first occurrence of those spaces in the
                    # record with 4 spaces (this does not change the format). 
  }
  1                 # Print the record.
' file
```

Comment: This works perfectly, can you explain the first one a little bit for me? Thanks.

Comment: @user2197705 . Hi, you are welcome. I added an explanation, I hope it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sed:

```
$ sed -r '4,$s/^([^ ]*)/\1 /' file
060A    2012075  2014035   27.0361  -80.3618    0.0090 Indiantown, FL, USA                                -    -         0.0000    0.0000 04/04/14 11:36:27
060A    2012075  2014035   27.0361  -80.3618    0.0090 Indiantown, FL, USA                                -    -         0.0000    0.0000 04/04/14 11:36:27
058A    2012071  2013313   27.0569  -81.8049    0.0150 Arcadia, FL, USA                                   -    -         0.0000    0.0000 04/09/14 10:20:19
059A    2012072  2013313   26.9671  -81.1440    0.0110 Moore Haven, FL, USA                               -    -         0.0000    0.0000 04/09/14 10:20:19
059Z    2012073  2013315   26.3373  -81.4432    0.0080 Ave Maria, FL, USA                                 -    -         0.0000    0.0000 04/09/14 10:20:19
060A    2012075  2014035   27.0361  -80.3618    0.0090 Indiantown, FL, USA                                -    -         0.0000    0.0000 04/09/14 10:20:19
060Z    2012134  2013317   26.4062  -80.5560    0.0090 West Palm Beach, FL, USA                           -    -         0.0000    0.0000 04/09/14 10:20:19
```

#### Explanation

- `-r` allows catching groups wit `()` instead of `\( \)`. If you don't use it, just use the other way.
- `4,$s/^([^ ]*)/\1 /'` catches, from line number 4 to the end, the first block and prints it back with one space.

Comment: I am sorry, i have edited the question. The format has to be exactly the same with the first three rows.

Comment: But this is adding one space after 1st field from row 4 to the end. Isn't it what you want? Also, if you edit your question with an image, people won't be able to copy paste to test.